# Another variation of the 'Sharpe ratio' in CVaR-based portfolio optimization?

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization, portfolio, modern-portfolio-theory, sharpe-ratio

### **Question**

- What is the ratio S(*p*) shown below? Do we have a name for it like 'Sharpe ratio'?[image: image[1]]
- The ratio above is introduced in the academic paper *[Optimal portfolio selection in a Value-at-Risk framework](https://pages.nes.ru/agoriaev/Papers/Campbell%20Optimal%20portfolio%20selection%20in%20a%20Value-at-Risk%20framework%20JBF01.pdf)*
- The author of the paper said that from the CVaR point of view, **the best portfolio is the one which maximizes the ratio S(*p*)**.

### What notation means

- **r(*p*)** : the expected total return on a portfolio *p* for a certain period.
- **r<sub>f</sub>** : the risk-free rate
- **W(0)** : the amount of the initial wealth
- **q(c,*p*)** : the quantile that corresponds to probability (1-c) of occurrence, which can be read off the cdf of the expected return distribution for portfolio *p*

### One example helping to understand the ratio S(*p*)

- Let's suppose that the expected annual return of your portfolio is 5%, **r(*p*) = 5%**.
- The annual risk-rate is 2%, **r<sub>f</sub> = 2%**.
- The bottom 10% expected annual return of the probability distribution of your portfolio is -50%. (It means the probability distribution is left-tailed very much). **q(0.9,*p*) = -50%**
- My initial wealth is $ 1,000.
- Then **S(*p*)** is (5% - 2%) / (1000 * 2% - 1000 * (-50%) ) = 3% / 520 = **0.006%**
- If the probability distribution of my portfolio is less left-tailed, let's say **q(0.9,*p*) = 1%**, then **S(*p*) = 0.3%** ( 3% / 10 ), which is much bigger than 0.006% previously.
- So I can see why the author of the academic paper said to maximize the ratio S(*p*) to get the best portfolio from the CVaR viewpoint, but I am curious to know if the ratio has any official name, such as Sharpe ratio.

Comment: The ratio does not have an official name, but risk-reward ratio is probably generic enough.

Comment: @John Thanks for your helpful comment! Then do we have any portfolio performance measure as popular as Sharpe ratio, which can be applied to CVaR based portfolios?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from calculating the risk-reward ratio using CVaR as your measure of risk. However, it can be tricky to interpret, particularly relative to a Sharpe ratio. You may find better luck using CVaR deviation, which is CVaR minus the expected return.